# Why doesn't the `alert` function work, if passed alone, in this react component?

Tags: reactjs

I have just been looking at React and realised that although event handlers need a function as an argument... For some reason, `alert` doesn't seem to work here.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello React World</h1>
      <h2 onClick={alert("you clicked the message!")}>Hello World</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, if I wrap the alert function within another function, it works. Why? `alert()` itself is a function that should work, correct?

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello React World</h1>
      <h2 onClick={()=> alert("you clicked the message!")}>Hello World</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In the first you are not passing it a function, you are calling one which will be responsible for assigning `onClick`. This means `alert` is called at the time of render, and `onClick` gets assigned `undefined`. The second is passed a function that is called when clicked.

Comment: Aaah............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the reference to the function, not call the function

This code calls the function directly

```
<h2 onClick={alert("you clicked the message!")}>Hello World</h2>
```

This code though calls the function only when clicked

```
<h2 onClick={()=> alert("you clicked the message!")}>Hello World</h2>
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much.

Comment: hey there ! just on the side tho,  if you have to bind the alert function and pass it to onClick to what would you bind it ?

Comment: @TilakMaddy sorry I didn't understand what you want to do. Can you tell me again?

Comment: I mean like `onClick=alert.bind(this, "You clicked the message")` .... passing `this` as the first argument is wrong. so what should we pass